# How to show Overall Percentage of Task completed out of 7 Different Task Lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, tasks

I need to find a solution that would allow to show the overall % of Task completed till date based on the TASK completed in 7 Different TASK Lists.

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Please suggest how can I achieve it.

Comment: What are you own initial thoughts on which SP components *could* do (part of) the job?

Comment: SPLIST.ITEM.Count

Comment: Very good, That's the info for one List, What technologies (plural) could you use to get all seven Lists?

Comment: @ I know I sound a fool, but trust me I dont have the knowledge and that is what I'm asking the experts. So I can work on it and get the derived solution.

Comment: I know, I am a tough teacher letting students figure out the answers for themselves. If you come up with SPLIST.ITEM.Count then I know you know more than the average user... So.. What technologies get you all the Lists you are *searching* for? Can it be done with a WebPart maybe? Which WebPart would that be?... Sure I **can** do you job.. but then I want your paycheck as well.